# Print a sentence with placeholder and function from an external file. Problem with importing forms, using and retrieving content

Tags: python, string, tkinter, module

I made a program that prints some text in a sentence with two placeholders. When the user selects a tournament name from the left-hand combobox and a team name from the right-hand combobox, a template string is filled in with those values and written in the bottom text field. It looks like:

I was able to get this working with all the code in a single file. Now I am trying to organize the code into three separate Python files, thus:

- `Main.py`: Contains the main code; accesses the template string from `Template.py`
- `Template.py`: Contains the template string that will be filled out; calls the `getArticle` function from `Grammar.py` and also gets the team name from `Main.py` (by checking the combobox contents)
- `Grammar.py`: provides `getArticle`, which uses dictionaries from `Main.py` to determine the article that should appear before the team name

**PROBLEM** Now when I start the program, I get the error:

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'Template' has no attribute 'test_template' (most likely due to a circular import).

I tried fixing this by moving an import into a function to defer it; but then `subject = team.get()` still does not work in `Template.py`.

**HOW DOES MY CODE WORK?** I select the element in the first combobox (for example Serie A), then I select the element of the second combobox (for example Atalanta). Then I click on Print. When I click on Print the purpose is to print test_template = f "Bla bla bla {article} {subject}". Subject is the second combobox (for example Atalanta). Article is selected by means of the `GetArticle` function and dictionaries. This function is used to understand which article to print in relation to the subject. When I had all the code in one file, it worked fine.

How can I print `test_template` in `Main.py`, *while altering the code structure as little as possible*? I specifically want to keep using three files, with `test_template` being located in `Template.py` and `getArticle` being in `Grammar.py`.

**NOTE 1:** Possibly, I don't need the sentence to be the return of a function, because my code is an example, but I will have to use hundreds of sentences, so I need a lot of variables (such as example `test_template` in my code). I would like to use test_template1 as I did in my code. If you really need the function, then know that in the future I will have to use many "random" variables (test_template1, test_template2, test_template3, etc.) and so I don't want to use the return only directly in the return row.

I would need a return of test_template (+ e.g. test_template2, test_template3, etc.) that is compatible with using "random" in Main.py, so for example have in Main: `random_template_test = random.choice ([test_template, test_template2 , test_template3])`.

**NOTE 2:** Also I need to pass `{article}` `{subject}` without distorting the reason too much (obviously modifying a little, but not too much), because then in the future I should also print other placeholders taking them from Main.py and Grammar.py.

For reference, here is the complete code:

### Template.py

```
import Grammar
import Main

test_template = f"Bla bla bla {article} {subject}"

#Subject is created in the Main.py file
#While Article is created in the Grammar.py file
subject = team.get()
article = getArticle(subject)
```

### Grammar.py

```
import Main

from Main import teams
from Main import article_words
from Main import nouns

#Subject is created in the Main.py file
def getArticle(subject):
    for key, value in article_words.items():
        if nouns[subject] == value:
            return key
```

### Main.py

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import Template

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x150")
   
tournament=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 18)
tournament.place(x=15, y=15)
tournament['value'] = ["Serie A", "Serie B"]
tournament.set("Tournament")

def on_tournament_selected(event):
    # Clear the entry boxes: aggiunto io
    team.delete(0,'end') 
    
    req_teams = [] # For all the required teams
    sel_tournament = tournament.get() # Get the tournament
    
    # get the names for selected gender
    for _team in teams.items(): # Go through all the teams in the dictionary
        key = _team[0] # Get the key
        value = _team[1] # Get the value 
        if value['Tournament'] == sel_tournament: # If Tournament of the loop-ed team is our selected tourname, then 
            req_teams.append(key)
    
    team.config(values=req_teams) # Change the values of the combobox

tournament.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_tournament_selected)

#############

team=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 18)
team.place(x=200, y=15)
team.set("Teams")

text = tk.Text(root,width=43,height=2)
text.place(x=15, y=50)

def printTeam():
    #here first there was subject and article, then moved to another external file
    
    def articolo1():
        template1 = Template.test_template
        text.insert(tk.END, template1)

    articolo1()

button2 = Button(root, text="Print", command = printTeam)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=15, y=100)

#DICT
teams = {
            "Atalanta": {
                "Nome Squadra": "Atalanta",
                "Tournament": "Serie A",
        },


            "Bologna": {
                "Nome Squadra": "Bologna",
                "Tournament": "Serie A",
        }
   }
       
nouns = {

        "Atalanta": {"genere" : "femminile", "unità" : "singolare", "apostrofo" : "si"},
        "Bologna": {"genere" : "maschile", "unità" : "singolare", "apostrofo" : "no"},
        }

article_words = {
    
            "del" : {
            "genere" : "maschile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            "apostrofo": "no"
            },        
                      
            "dell'" : {
            "genere" : "femminile",
            "unità" : "singolare",
            "apostrofo" : "si"
            },                
        }

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Move `import Template` into `def articolo1():`.

Comment: @aaron Following your suggestion, I get the error: template1 = Template.test_template
NameError: name 'Template' is not defined, because I can no longer get the template inside the template.py file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you create a repro project on GitHub?

Comment: Can it be a problem because of the circular import between `TEMPLATE.py` and `MAIN.py`?

Comment: Also, as seen in the `TEMPLATE.py` file, you are importing `Main` but still retrieving the subject as `subject = team.get()` instead of `subject = Main.team.get()`

Comment: Why would you want to keep a bad structure with circular imports? You will have to change some of the structure.

Comment: @Art I would like to keep the 3 files. The important thing is that test_template is inside Template.py; that the function gets both the article inside the grammar.py (because that function represents the grammar): for the rest you can modify as you see fit. Main.py can also be modified as you see fit. Can you help me solve? Thank you

Comment: @Jas_99 what exactly does your template file do?

Comment: I made significant [edit]s to the question in order to make it understandable - by reorganizing it, cleaning up things that were said multiple times or were irrelevant, trying to fix some terminology, etc. However, there is still a lot of work that needs to be done here. First, please read [ask] and [mre], and try to cut out things that are irrelevant to the problem. For example, does the structured data need to have the full set of values, or all of that complexity, in order to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Second: try to show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error messages, and make sure they correspond to code that's actually in the post. If you tried something that solves the circular import problem and runs into a different problem, then that is a *separate question* - I would advise you to hold off on that for now, since the problem can be solved more elegantly. Please [edit] the question again and make sure I have correctly understood the problem, and fix anything that still needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Art I select the element in the first combobox (for example Serie A), then I select the element of the second combobox (for example Atalante). Then I click on Print. When I click on Print the purpose is to print test_template = f "Bla bla bla {article} {subject}". Subject is the second combobox (for example Atalanta). Article is selected by means of the GetArticle function and dictionaries. This function is used to understand which article to print in relation to the subject. When I had all the code in one file, it worked fine.

Comment: Make `Template` a class with `team` as an argument in constructor. Write an instance method in that class to return `test_template`. Create an instance of the `Template` object in `articolo1()` or where ever you want `test_template`. In short, refactor code using object oriented design.

Comment: It's fine that there are three files; we need that to understand the problem. But maybe we can take out part of the file contents. For example, can we cause the problem without using Tkinter? Can we cause the problem if `article_words` is just a string, and `get_article` just returns that string? Again, please *read* [mre].

Comment: *How can I print test_template in Main.py* what does this mean? You said that you have many variables to be printed. Please be specific about your question.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel If we delete some of the contents of the file, the problem is not caused. If I delete Tkinter the problem is not caused. If I delete or modify article_words and get_article the problem is not caused. I understand that you need to moderate user questions, but my question unfortunately needs that code in order to get the problem. Now, however, I try to remove as much code as possible

Comment: I guarantee you that I can demonstrate the problem with shorter code. (However, it is not feasible to show it in a comment, and not appropriate on Stack Overflow to use the answer section just to show that.) Keep in mind that Stack Overflow questions need to be **one** question - if the question is about the circular import, then it is not also a general debugging request.

Comment: @Art I will add the variables myself privately. I said this, to make you understand how I need to retrieve the print result as a variable like "test_template" (not as a result of the function as you wrote before). "How can I print test_template in Main.py" means I would like to print the variable called test_template in the Main.py textbox

Comment: @Jas_99, how exactly do you plan to pass `article` and `subject` into your sentences?

Comment: I think you should be open to learning different and new solutions. You are unnecessarily adding constraints making your own code more complex and unmaintainable in the long run.

Comment: @Art In fact, as I asked in the question, my problem was the import and pass article and subject into your sentences. It is right that everyone should be open to learning different and new solutions, but if I wrote the code that way in the question I have my precise reasons. I don't think it's impossible to solve. Then if someone wants to propose different solutions, they are welcome :), but I would like my code not to be too distorted because the code posted here is only a small part of a larger code. However, I am waiting for users who want to help me I hope. Thank you

Comment: @Jas_99 What you ask isn't how python or programming languages generally works. You can't pass any subject or article without using a function to return the modified sentences. This question is whats known as [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Can you create a repro project on GitHub?

Comment: This question is being discussed on [the meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419556/2821954).

Comment: Did you read the part, that what you are asking for is impossible (said by other viewers) ?

Comment: This question need to focus on one issue. The OP has pointed out multiple needs and thus this question should be closed due to needing more focus. I think the OP would benefit from asking one question at a time as needed. I have flagged it to be closed in order to allow the OP to ask one question at a time.

Comment: You need to work your idea out first and then come to [so] with a specific kind of problem you need help with. You seem confused, there is no doubt about it, but your question and your bounty will nothing but frustrating you and others. You because you wont get an quality answer and people willing to help, trying figuring out what you want. You seem at a point where you are interested in [structuring your project](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/)  and [databases](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/db/). Please do some research before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the dictionaries in dicts.py and create a class in template.py to return required template.You can create as many templates as you want in templates.py.

### **dicts.py**

```
teams = {...}
   
nouns = {...}

article_words = {...}
```

### **template.py**

```
from grammer import getArticle
import random

class Template():

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

        # must define other variables like article which are used
        # in templates irrespective of the arguments passed

        if self.subject:
            self.article = getArticle(subject=self.subject)

    def return_template(self):
        test_template_list = ["Bla bla bla {subject} {article}", "Again bla bla bla {subject}"]
        test_template = random.choice(test_template_list)

        place_holders = ['{subject}','{article}', ]

        for i in place_holders:
            if i in test_template:
                test_template=test_template.replace(i,(self.__dict__[i.lstrip("{").rstrip("}")]))
        
        return test_template
```

### **grammer.py**

```
from dicts import article_words, nouns

def getArticle(subject):
    for key, value in article_words.items():
        if nouns[subject] == value:
            return key
```

### **main.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from template import Template
from dicts import teams

root = Tk()
root.geometry("420x150")

tournament=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 18)
tournament.place(x=15, y=15)
tournament['value'] = ["Serie A", "Serie B"]
tournament.set("Tournament")

def on_tournament_selected(event):
    team.delete(0,'end') 

    req_teams = [] 
    sel_tournament = tournament.get() 

    for key,value in teams.items():
        if value['Tournament'] == sel_tournament:
            req_teams.append(key)

    team.config(values=req_teams)

tournament.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", on_tournament_selected)

team=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 18)
team.place(x=215, y=15)
team.set("Teams")

text = Text(root,width=43,height=2)
text.place(x=15, y=50)

def printTeam():
    template1 = Template(subject=team.get()) # pass keyword arguments
    text.insert(END, template1.return_template())

button2 = Button(root, text="Print", command = printTeam)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=15, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

The error was due to circular imports in your files.

Comment: The author doesn't want to move the `test_template` to a function or a method. I had proposed two other similar solutions which were downvoted by the author. What the author wants is to pass articles and subject placeholders without the variable being in a function, which seems impossible. So there is no point in proposing more similar solutions unless the author thinks of turning around, and probably being accepting of more different solutions, that can easily solve his/her problem.

Comment: ya, it seems impossible that way

Comment: @Art You did not understand. I would rather not have the function, but if it is needed, ok, ok, I want to move test_template into a function :) But I want to get one or more variables returned in the return. In your old answer, you didn't do it this way, but you created the sentence with the placeholders directly in the return. Just because I didn't like your answer, there is no need to speak ill of me. You are creating comments and requests to close my question, just because I did not like your answer (deleted) and you are looking for revenge. It's not like that! Be more respectful. Thank you

Comment: @blaze2004 PART 1. We are approaching the solution. I thank you :). I had expressed those words about the function, because I need to get various variables to print in Main by means of random.choice. I didn't say random so as not to dwell on it. I just needed several variables to return. For example, if in your function return_template1 you had test_template2 in addition to test_template, I would like to print one of the two random variables in Main. So how could I use random.choice with test_template and test_template2?

Comment: @blaze2004 PART 2. Normally just write random.choice ([x, y]), I know, but in this case they are variables returned by an external function.
I was thinking something like random_template_test = random.choice ([template1.return_template1.test_template, template1.return_template1.test_template2]),
but it does not work. Is your answer compatible to use test_template, test_template2, test_template3 (for example) inside random? Thank you

Comment: you can check the updated solution, if you go by this method then I would suggest you to  declare test_template_list in dicts.py file.

Comment: @blaze2004 I would have preferred to use random.choise inside the main.py file, but that's okay as well as you did with random in template.py. Good idea of the list, great! But I don't like using .format (self.subject, self.article), because I would have to use many other placeholders (about 50) and I can't specify them all in format, it would be too repetitive work. I was thinking of using "return test_template, test_template2, test_template3" and then using them with random inside Main, but maybe that's not good. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks again for both your kindness and attention

Comment: do different templates have different number of placeholders?

Comment: @blaze2004 yes, different templates have different number of placeholders

Comment: is there any relationship between placeholders and the template, means on what criteria you fill place holders given the template

Comment: @blaze2004 Yes. The placeholders are filled with the selection of various comboboxes. For each item in the combobox there are conditions that correspond to a placeholder

Comment: check the updated answer, now the placeholders are defined with their names and if it found in template then they are replaced by their values. Important point to note is that you should define every placeholder value which does not comes from main e.g article

Comment: @blaze2004 For example if I select the contents of a combobox in Main.py and I get the variable var1 = "var_example", how should I put it in test_template_list? Thank you

Comment: give the variable some meaningful name and then use the same name in test_template_list and place_holders. e.g if var1 then use {var1} in test_tesmplate_list and place_holders

Comment: @blaze2004 I wrote like this, but I get an error. What am I doing wrong? https://ibb.co/nQM9MYm

Comment: @blaze2004 For distraction (when I changed the name of the variable) I wrote wrong as you see, but it is not important, because correcting I still get the error: self.var1 = var1
NameError: name 'var1' is not defined

Comment: the link you sent is not working

Comment: you don't need to manually declare variables which you pass from  main.py. They are added by `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)`. as any variable you declare by `self.var=2` is add to `self.__dict__` dictionary so you don't need to do that again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246956/discussion-between-jas-99-and-blaze2004).

Comment: There are several ways to substitute variables in strings (other than f-strings) which are better than using replace. See [String format() Method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method) and [printf-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

Comment: Ah I see @Jas_99 has mentioned they don't want to use `.format()`. What stops you from using something like `"{foo}".format(**{"foo":1,"bar":2})` or `"{foo}".format(**my_dictionary)`?

Comment: FOR READERS: I am not satisfied with the answer. Not what I was looking for. But I want to accept the answer because I am polite and respect the user who still spent his time to "try" to help me. Too bad for all those negative ratings. A user was angry with me because I said I didn't like his response, so he took his revenge by opening a post on Meta. It takes respect for everyone

Comment: @blaze2004 I am not satisfied with the answer. Not what I was looking for. But I want to accept the answer because I'm polite I respect you (you still spent your time "trying" to help me, thanks)